# How to leverage dependencies in referenced TypeScript projects?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, project-reference

I'm trying to understand how to break apart my pretty large TypeScript section of a SPA (React with Asp Net 6 as backend).

Let's consider this basic structure:

```
WebAppSolution
  SharedProject
    lib
      (TS sources)
    node_modules
    tsconfig.json
    package.json

  WebAppProject
    (C# sources)
    Scripts
      (TS sources)
    node_modules
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
    webpack.config.js
```

I mean that `WebAppSolution` includes `WebAppProject` and they live in a dedicated repo. `SharedProject` will have its own repo and it is referred by the solution. Moreover, `SharedProject` is meant as a general-purpose project reusable by other applications. In short, `SharedProject` should act as a NPM package for `WebAppProject`, but without the hassle of publishing it at every single modification (actually I'll have several shared projects to refer).

So far, I've been able to make it work something.

In `SharedProject` I have just this basic service to expose. Of course, the project has [lodash](https://lodash.com/) as npm installed dependency:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";

export function sum(a: number, b: number): [number, boolean] {
    const result = a + b;
    return [
        result,
        _.isFinite(result)
    ]
}
```

On the other side, in `WebAppProject` I have a script which consumes the service:

```
import * as myLib from "../../SharedProject/lib";

const a = 10;
const b = 25;
const result = myLib.sum(a, b);

console.log(`Ciao: ${result[0]}; ${result[1]}; ${ia}`);
```

Everything works perfectly.

The problem happens when I try to leverage `lodash` from the `SharedProject` instead of installing in the `WebAppProject` as well. I cannot figure how to solve it (whereas it is possible).

```
import * as myLib from "../../SharedProject/lib";
import * as _ from "lodash";  //error TS2307: Build:Cannot find module 'lodash'...

const a = 10;
const b = 25;
const result = myLib.sum(a, b);

const ia = _.isArray([]);

console.log(`Ciao: ${result[0]}; ${result[1]}; ${ia}`);
```

I tried also by expliciting the `lodash` path, but I would avoid to specify this info in every single module. At config level would be perfectly acceptable, instead.

```
import * as myLib from "../../SharedProject/lib";
import * as _ from "../../SharedProject/node_modules/lodash";

const a = 10;
const b = 25;
const result = myLib.sum(a, b);

const ia = _.isArray([]);

console.log(`Ciao: ${result[0]}; ${result[1]}; ${ia}`);
```

This works, however there's no symbols available for `lodash`.

If I install `lodash` as dependency also in the `WebAppProject`, it works, but then the resulting bundle actually embeds the library twice and that's not acceptable.
Note that I say "bundle", because the resulting script is bundled via webpack at the `WebAppProject` level, then served to the browser.

Finally, is there a way to leverage the already installed npm's, together with the symbols?
Is this approach worthwhile or are there suggestion to manage in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

In the `WebAppProject`'s `package.json` the dependencies should be added and should point to the related `SharedProject` folder:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-css": "^5.2.4",
    ...
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-merge-and-include-globally": "^2.3.3",
    "@types/lodash": "file:../SharedProject /node_modules/@types/lodash"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.9",
    "lodash": "file:../SharedProject /node_modules/lodash"
  }
```

Also important to run `npm install` for this package.

More info here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths